# Dealing with blocks in yacc

Tags: c, yacc

I'm building a parser with lex + yacc for the following simple language:

```
lines are parsed ok

foo {
   lines of the "foo" category come here
} # closing this block
```

The following definition of block in my grammar worked:

```
item : block
     | lines; /* lines without a block */

block: WORD BRACE_OPEN NL lines BRACE_CLOSE
     { printf("category: %s\n", $1 );}
```

The problem is that the `printf` happens **after** the block has been parsed, but I need to get the category name ("foo" in the example) as an information to parse lines within the block.

I came up with a solution but it doesn't seem very elegant:

```
item : line
     | block_open
     | block_close;

block_open : WORD BRACE_OPEN { printf("%s {\n", $1); };

block_close : BRACE_CLOSE { printf("}\n"); };
```

I can now fetch the "category" name when opening the block.  But would that be the right or the best approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
block: WORD BRACE_OPEN NL lines BRACE_CLOSE
    { printf("category: %s\n", $1 );}
```

You can put an action anywhere (although it may cause s/r conflicts):

```
block
    : WORD
        { printf("category: %s\n", $1 );}
      BRACE_OPEN NL lines BRACE_CLOSE
    ;
```

which is equivalent to

```
block
    : category BRACE_OPEN NL lines BRACE_CLOSE
    ;
category
    : WORD
        { printf("category: %s\n", $1 );}
    ;
```

You may prefer the latter.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that the printf happens after the block has been parsed

This is because yacc is a bottom-up parser. The leaves of the AST are built before the intermediate nodes.

If you want the type of block to affect the parsing inside it, a top-down approach (like a recursive descent parser) might be more natural.

> but I need to get the category name ("foo" in the example) as an information to parse lines within the block.

I think the most straightforward way to do that would be to have a different grammar rule for each kind of block instead of having a generic "block" rule. For example:

```
foo_block: FOO BRACE_OPEN foo_lines BRACE_CLOSE;

bar_block: BAR BRACE_OPEN bar_lines BRACE_CLOSE;

baz_block: BAZ BRACE_OPEN baz_lines BRACE_CLOSE;
```

This assumes that "foo" and "bar" and "baz" are keywords that the lexer knows about and not just generic WORDs.

Comment: Does the syntax for the lines inside the block vary depending on what category it is?

Comment: Nah, it is the same syntax of lines outside of the "category" block.